# Unhappy with Project management

Tags: manager, project-management, developer

It's been 4 months into my Android Dev job, and I have to work on 3 projects simultaneously - as a developer. All 3 are approximately the same app, with some differences, but nothing excessive.

I think I am unsatisfied of 2 of these projects.

The one that I like is, from my opinion, well managed. Once or twice a week I have a meeting, 15-20 minutes, where everyone tells their problems or what they need. If someone needs something from me, they ask me by IM or Mail, and wait for me to do it.

The other projects are not that organized. One have these 15-20 minutes meetings, once a week, except it actually lasts 1 or 2 hours. Nothing goes forward, and subjects that are very specific or technic often takes more than half the meeting. I get interrupted a lot, and I can't talk about what I need to say. I'm getting really irritated about this, so I leave the meeting after my "turn".

During the week, I have to walk in front of the project's office, because it's in the way of the break room. When I walk there it's either because I'm going to take a coffee, or I go back to my desk. They don't seem to care about this, as they run before me (yes really, I'm trying to pass quick and they leave their desk to catch me) and say every problem they have with my application, bugs, issues, even if I obviously have my coffee cup in hand.

The other project asks for unreasonable deadlines, even though all other parts are not ready (Basically asking for an app before having user management, so you can't login to test)
I tried to explain the manager that he doesn't need to have my app absolutely today, because nobody will use it in two weeks, so he can let me work a little bit on it before delivering it.

I tried to talk to the project managers, but they basically laugh at me like "Our meeting is said to be the best of all projects" or "You need to give me the app today, I know the other parts are not ready but they will do it today (17h30...)

I don't know what can I do to get better management, because I don't think it's productive, it gives me a lot of stress and I can't work well under pressure.

Thank you for your feedback !

Comment: "`All 3 are approximately the same app, with some differences, but nothing excessive`" - so why are you developing three? Do you use common code, with 3 add-ons for the variants?

Comment: That's more or less the point. There is common code, and a "Product" app, which is generic

Comment: I feel your pain :-(  "`I tried to talk to the project managers, but they basically laugh at me`" should make it plain what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can *you personally* do about this, as a relatively new member of the company? Get yourself a little better organized.  You can't change the behavior of other people, only yourself.  (That will probably change over time as you gain seniority.)

You have more work to do each day than you can finish. That's perfectly normal in the workplace. With respect, you should get used to it.  But, how do you cope with it?

**Ask for help:** Approach your supervisor, them you're having trouble because you have too many top priorities, and ask for advice and help. People love being asked for advice.

**Priorities:** Here's what I have done. I keep a list of the tasks facing me, and I keep it in priority order. I regularly review it with my supervisor and ask for suggestions. What tasks have I missed? Do I have my priorities right? Then I work on the top two or three tasks until they're crossed off the list, ignoring the lower-priority ones.

The point here is to make this priority list into your supervisor's priority list for your work.

In your situation you would be wise to bring your priority list to your project meetings, and to revise it immediately after each project meeting to reflect requests made of you. And, get your supervisor's feedback promptly.

**Customer satisfaction:** You also appear to have a problem with "customer" satisfaction. (Your customers are the people who want you to do things.) They chase you around the office asking for tasks they expect you to do. That's unpleasant for you, and surely for them too. What can you do about this?  **Set expectations.** Be clear and let your "customers" know what you can do for them and when. Tell them whether their tasks are your highest priority, or not. When they demand that you change your priorities, ask them to speak to your supervisor about your priorities.

If your supervisor can't or won't help you with this, you might approach one of your company's project managers and ask for this help.

And remember this: your scrambling around is not just a problem for you, it's also a problem for your supervisor and your company. They have a big stake in helping you with it. Do your best to overcome your frustration and treat it as a business problem rather than a personal problem.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are a Project Manager

Proper management is not done by discussions. Is by having a very clear list of problems, proper analysis to be done by the proper people in the project, tasks assigned.

Bug management systems do that generally. They can be used for coffee machine replacements or chair repairs too, if nothing better exists. The project in those cases could be "Building administration"

You, and your teams, have the wrong understanding, it seems. Your job is not to do the project. It is to help the people to do the project. You need to make sure you understand the problems and assign them to the right people. And then the people have to deliver. If they do not deliver, you escalate. Maybe they need trainings, maybe they need other resources, maybe they need to be fired. Each case must be dealt with individually.

---

Group meeting are not there do publicly discuss all the problems of the project. They have to be used only for the topics which affect more people. For other situations, 1-to-1 meetings have to be organized.

Also there are many kinds of meetings which should be organized by the PM:

- regular team meeting;
- regular core team meeting;
- risk management meeting;
- regular stakeholders meetings;
- regular reporting meetings;
- others.

---

So my bottom line understanding is that you really need a good training (or more) in project management. Your first project is just a happy case, it just happens without much of your involvement.

### If you are a Developer

Send your colleagues to the proper project managers to get their answers. Ask your managers to prioritize your work, if you are not able to do your job in the given amount of time.

> say every problem they have with my application, bugs, issues

If you have so much feedback and problems because of the bugs in your own part of the application, then you should start asking yourself `why do you actually "implement" so many bugs` in the first place?

> yes really, I'm trying to pass quick

Running away from responsibility is not the good way.

> The other project asks for unreasonable deadlines

Then you need to escalate the problem to the project managers and your supervisor (or however they are called in your company). They have to help you by prioritizing your work.

> even if I obviously have my coffee cup in hand

Partially joking: maybe you should stop drinking so much coffee and start fixing those bugs :)

As a **conclusion**, you have to understand why you are the only one delivering so many problems. Understand where you need to improve. Maybe you need technical trainings (programming, architecture, best practices...) or soft skills trainings (communication, time management, stress management, conflict avoidance...). he right persons to support you with this are... the project managers and you supervisor.

Comment: I think you get it wrong, I'm not the project manager, I'm a developer who thinks management is not good and I feel that my work is affected by this

Comment: :O Then why does everyone come to you to solve problems?!?! Are you the worst developer in the company, but still assigned to all projects? :) Joke aside, please clarify this topic by editing the question.

Comment: I don't know how to edit this... I don't know if i'm the worst developer, but each one from my team has at least 3 projects to work on

Comment: Under the question there is a button labeled "edit" (actually just some gray text, not really a button). Use it, and then add the information that you are a developer. And explain why everybody expects answers from you, instead of someone else.

Comment: I said it in the first sentence :) I will edit why people need my answers !

Comment: I read your first sentence at least 10 times. It is still not more clear which is your role in the project. Are you aware that what PMs do is also called `work`?

Comment: I thought Android Dev was clear enough...

Comment: For me, dev = development, and that includes also the project management, among others.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things you can try:

When a meeting is going off-track, point it out. If it's a few people discussing something in detail that doesn't concern the rest of you, ask if they could leave that issue for a separate meeting, so the rest of you can get on with the rest of the agenda.

When someone interrupts you and gives you a new task, ask where it fits in with the other tasks they've given you ("should I do this before of after that other thing?") and let them know if you have other priorities ("sorry, I'm in the middle of doing A for X, then I've got to do B for Z, but I can start your task tomorrow afternoon.")